# Environment specific configurations for Spartacus on ccv2

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have a requirement to use a different apiKeyGigya per environment specific configuration for Spartacus on ccv2.

I tried to solve this by using multiple environment.xxx.ts files in which I defined the apiKey. However, in ccv2 environments only one command is being executed which is "build:ssr" in the build process.

I use the following tags for the corresponding environments:

1. Environment Production "build:ssr"
2. Environment Development "build:ssr-d1"
3. Environment Staging "build:ssr-s1"

Does anyone have a solution for this case?
Could you support me, please

Does anyone have a solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for different build targets in Spartacus and SAP does not offer an official solution for this.

A possible solution to this, is moving your environment specific properties to your backend properties files. With the manifest, you can load in different properties files in the different environments.

You then create a new OCC endpoint, where you fetch your environment specific configuration based on the environment key. This can contain different values per environment.

For performance reasons, you could also have this endpoint serve all configurations in 1 response, cache this in Spartacus and use accordingly.

There were quite some discussions on this topic on the github repo. https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/5772